# How to spawn a new shell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, shell

I am developing a Mysql based file system for Linux system. I have developed python code to implement basic linux terminal command like cd,ls,pwd,find and grep.

Currently I am running my python file in terminal using `python filename.py`, in this case all the functions I wrote has to be executed in the same terminal.

Requirement: As soon I run my python script in terminal ,is there a way to spawn a separate shell to execute my commands. i.e instead of using the existing linux terminal, I need to use a new shell prompted by my python code.

Current output is as in below image:

[image: screenshot]

Please suggest ways to achieve my requirement.

Comment: Are you not using the shell that your python program spawns?

Comment: As shown in the image, I am using the shell spawned by python but in the same terminal where I executed my python file.

Comment: So you want to spawn two terminal instances, one for your shell and one for your python instance?

Comment: Yeah, that would suffice my requirement.

Comment: Can you share the output of `echo $TERM`?

Comment: Do you me python filename.py echo $TERM ?   -> in this case same as above shown figure.   For terminal $ echo $TERM -> it's just a blank line

Comment: No, just `echo $TERM` on the shell.

Comment: Then it's just a blank line

Comment: Probably can be done with the pty library. Maybe something like pty.spawn("/bin/bash") or one of the other functions from the library, I think allows you to spawn programs and get a file descriptor to communicate with them